# vue app calls the backend from the client origin (ip+port) but not from the frontend server

Tags: vue.js, fastapi

I am new to vue and maybe I miss some fundamental concept here but I am not able to force my vue app to call the backend from the frontend server origin (ip:port). It seems that the API calls arriving from the client IPs instead - cause an issue that the backend CORS control cannot work.

I try to create a simple hello-world app and host a separate backend and frontend server in a docker container on a NAS running at local network. The ip of the NAS on the local network is 192.168.0.150. I mapped the port: 5000 to the backend and 6080 to the frontend.

I use python fastAPI as a backend and vuejs as a frontend. everyting works fine if I allow all the origins in the fastapi.middleware.cors setting :

##### Backend - fastapi.middleware.cors settings :

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get("/")
def home(request:Request):
    client_host = request.client.host
    client_port= request.client.port
    return {"message": "Hello, World!","client_host": client_host,"client_port":client_port }
'''
```

##### frontend/src/main.js - axios setting

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://192.168.0.150:5000/';  // the FastAPI backend
```

##### frontend/view - api call:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ msg }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Ping',
  data() {
    return {
      msg: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getMessage() {
      axios.get('/')
        .then((res) => {
          this.msg = res.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          this.msg = error.msg;
        });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getMessage();
  },
};
</script>
```

regardless of how I host the Vue app (with dev server -npm run serve- or after a build with a HTTP server) the message above in the tmeplate shows the ip of the devices on the network from where the page is opened and not the frontend (192.168.0.150:6080) as I would expect.

So that if I set the fastapi middleware to restrict the origins then the API call fails:

```
allow_origins=["http://192.168.0.150:6080/"]
```

I also tried to set up a proxy, based on this: https://techformist.com/vuejs-proxy-error-for-backend-connection/ but keep the same behavior.

would you please help with what I miss here?
is my understanding wrong that the API should feel that it is called from the frontend host:port rather than the clients?

Comment: `http://192.168.0.150:6080/` is not an origin (because of the trailing slash); try dropping the latter.

Comment: @jub0bs thanks - it is right dropping the latter fast api validate the origin correctly. Then the only question remains that why the request.client.host at the backend shows the ip of the client device not the ip of the front-end server. Or it is supposed to be like this and I used a wrong tool for debbuging it?

Comment: Because the _client_ that makes the request to the backend _is the client_. The frontend service _only deliveres the content to the client_, any future requests are initiated by the _client_. The only thing that has a reference to the frontend server is the `Origin` header - which is what CORS validation happens against.